# How to create a json file which has name contains slashes >> Uncaught Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './global/sites.json'

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

> I want to create a folder (if folder does not exist) called
> *alexadata* and create a json file under this folder which contains 'data'  and named with slashes like ***global/sites.json***  , else
> just want to create this json file into the alexadata folder. But both
> of two status, I have an error **Uncaught Error: ENOENT: no such file
> or directory, open './global/sites.json'** where **if(err) return
> err;** line. If folder does not exist, then it is created but json
> file is not created and gives this error. How can I fix this issue?
> Please help me. Thank you in advance.

```
jsToJSON: async (data) => {
    
        try {

            let url = await page.url();

            const code = await page.evaluate(() => {
                return {
                    code: document.querySelector('#alx-content > div.row-fluid.TopSites.AlexaTool.padding20 > section.page-product-top > div > section > div.Foldering > div.each.current > a').innerText.toLowerCase()
                }
            });

            const fields = ['rank', 'name', 'url', 'last_update'];
            const json2csvParser = new Json2csvParser({ fields });

            var _path = path.join(__dirname,'alexadata');

            if (!fs.existsSync("alexadata")) {
                fs.mkdir("alexadata", (err) => {

                    if (err) return err;

                    fs.writeFileSync(`./${code.code}/sites.json`, JSON.stringify(data), 'utf-8', (err) => {

                        if (err) return err;

                        console.log("Directory and File Saved ");

                    });

                });
            } else {
                fs.writeFile(path.join(_path, `/${code.code}/sites.json`), JSON.stringify(data), 'utf-8', (err) => {

                    if (err) return err;

                    console.log("Directory and File Saved ");

                });
            }

        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to create the folder if it doesn't exist.

Comment: At first thank you so much for your answer. I already create alexadata folder and want to create json file named global/sites.json but I guess global is like folder name in here. How can I create this json file or is that possible?

Comment: Filenames cannot contain forward slashes (`/`); not in any common filesystem.

Comment: Oh I see thank you so much again.